# ZFS Pool on internal ssd partition disappears after reboot, pre-existing partition (whatever it is) pops up instead

Tags: macos, partitioning, ssd, filesystems, zfs

Mojave 10.14.6, OpenZFS installed with brew (OpenZFS on OS X 1.9.4 Mojave.pkg)

By "disappears" here I don't mean "it's not imported", I mean actually, really disappears (no output from `zpool import`). The problem - on that particular machine at least (a macbook pro 13 unibody), and on that specific partition - is reproducible. I create, I reboot, nothing is there anymore. `diskutil list` shows the pre-existing partition, as if my `zpool create` command never happened (HFS+, for example).

It happens on a SSD partition (disk0s3). Previous partitions are: disk0s1 EFI, disk0s2 APFS with the OS. There's also another internal disk (disk1, HDD, entirely devoted to ZFS), plus a bunch of usb disks with ZFS, no problem there.

Whenever I reboot, disk0s3 reverts back to whatever partition was there before creating a ZFS pool in its place, be it a fat32 one or a HFS one or whatever.

I've tried to search here and on the internet, but I found nothing and I got no effin' clue to whatever's going on. My search results are obscured by people that cannot find their pool because it's not automatically imported, but this is not my case at all. This is not the only macOS machine on which I use ZFS - on one machine in particular I have exactly the same configuration, with a pool on a SSD partition and a pool on a whole magnetic disk. I use ZFS on Linux too, and it's the first time I encounter a situation like this.

If anyone has any ideas about how to proceed, I would be grateful. I have posted this as a github issue on the OpenZFS on OSX project (https://github.com/openzfsonosx/openzfs/issues/15), but no answer. I will report information there too, if any comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, thanks to [this answer](https://openzfsonosx.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=3494&sid=24e2cb0bf3fa8308f37a7236770d0982) on the OpenZFS on OS X forum.

The problem is that, when creating a ZFS pool on a GPT partition, the type of the partition must be manually set outside of ZFS, as written on the [zpool's OpenZFS on OS X Documentation](https://openzfsonosx.org/wiki/Zpool):

> Note that if you partition the disk yourself, and specify a slice for ZFS, you are responsible for making sure the partition table shows the partition type is ZFS. This can be done with OS X's built-in "gpt" command or the easier to use "gdisk" command.

## Detailed solution

- Install gdisk with homebrew: `brew install gdisk`, then create your pool with `zpool create`.
- Start gdisk with `sudo gdisk /dev/diskX`
- Print the partition table using command `p`, identify the partition number of the partition that needs its type to be set.
- Change the type using command `t`, which asks for the partition number (choose the partition identified before) and the partition type (use `bf01`).
- Write the partition table to disk using command `w`.
- Exit from gdisk, reboot.

Here's the full gdisk usage example and output:

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/diskX
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.6

Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/diskX: 976773169 sectors, 465.9 GiB
Sector size (logical): 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): HGB0C1AB-0911-473A-AC20-B955064EG470
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 524309 sectors (256.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640       255080447   121.4 GiB   AF0A  Mac
   3       255080448       976248831   343.9 GiB   AF00

Command (? for help): t
Partition number (1-3): 3
Current type is AF00 (Apple HFS/HFS+)
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = AF00): bf01
Changed type of partition to 'Solaris /usr & Mac ZFS'

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!
```

## Appendix

Why the older partition in the other macbook worked out the box, with exactly the same configuration? I don't have a definitive answer. I've checked the partition type with `gdisk` and it's **wrong**: `AF00`, instead of `BF01` as it should. Nonetheless, everything works. The only difference I can think about is that it was created several years ago, with a much older ZFS installation (it could have been version 0.6 or 0.7), and the `zpool` command did something that make it recognisable by ZFS.